# Clear an input field with Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a variable below.

```
var newInput = {
   title: this.inputTitle.value,
   entry: this.inputEntry.value    
};
```

This is used by my input fields.

```
<input type="text" id="inputname" className="form-control" ref={el => this.inputTitle = el} />   
<textarea id="inputage" ref={el => this.inputEntry = el} className="form-control" />
<button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.sendthru}>Add</button>
```

Once I activate `{this.sendthru}` I want to clear my input fields. However, I am uncertain how to do so.

Also, as shown in this example, it was pointed out to me that I should use the `ref` property for input values. What I am unclear of is what exactly does it mean to have `{el => this.inputEntry = el}`. What is the significance of `el` in this situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use input type="reset"

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  text: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />  
  <input type="reset" defaultValue="Reset" />  
</form>
```

Answer (score 53):

Let me assume that you have done the 'this' binding of 'sendThru' function.

The below functions clears the input fields when the method is triggered.

```
sendThru() {
    this.inputTitle.value = "";
    this.inputEntry.value = "";
}
```

Refs can be written as inline function expression:

```
ref={el => this.inputTitle = el}
```

where `el` refers to the component.

When refs are written like above, React sees a different function object each time so on every update, ref will be called with null immediately before it's called with the component instance.

Read more about it [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what you mean by 'this' binding of sendthru function? As is, when I click I get an error of `cannot read property value of undefined`

Comment: Got it. Instead of using `this.refs.inputTitle.value=""` I used `this.inputTitle=""`, which did the trick.

Comment: 'sendThru' is a event handler for onClick function, React recommends to bind 'this' reference at your constructor method. example `constructor() { this.sendThru = this.sendThru.bind(this)}' or if you are not using ES6 classes for react component you could bind the this key word in your render method as `onClick={this.sendThru.bind(this)}`

Comment: Should just be ``this.inputTitle.value = "";``. React has deprecated use of ``this.refs``: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs

Answer (score 35):

Declare value attribute for input tag (i.e `value= {this.state.name}`) and if you want to clear this input value you have to use `this.setState({name : ''})`

PFB working code for your reference :

```
<script type="text/babel">
    var StateComponent = React.createClass({
        resetName : function(event){
            this.setState({
                name : ''
            });
        },
        render : function(){
            return (
                <div>
                    <input type="text" value= {this.state.name}/>
                    <button onClick={this.resetName}>Reset</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(<StateComponent/>, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>
```

Comment: Coming from angular: this seems like a two-way binding approach, which I like.

Comment: This only works if you also add logic to update `this.state.name` whenever there are key presses in the input. Otherwise it is frozen to `''`, the initial value of `'this.state.name`.

Comment: Jhee whizz, only solution that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: you don't always want this, every state change causes a rerender, and sometimes that is exactly what you want, but sometimes you want to be more specific

Answer (score 20):

I have a similar solution to @Satheesh using React hooks:

State initialization:

```
const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState('');
```

Input tag:

```
<input type="text" value={enteredText}  (event handler, classNames, etc.) />
```

Inside the event handler function, after updating the object with data from input form, call:

```
setEnteredText('');
```

Note:  This is described as 'two-way binding'

Comment: perfect solution when using React, thanks

Answer (score 19):

I'm not really sure of the syntax {el => this.inputEntry = el}, but when clearing an input field you assign a ref like you mentioned.

```
<input type="text" ref="someName" />
```

Then in the onClick function after you've finished using the input value, just use...

```
this.refs.someName.value = '';
```

**Edit**

Actually the {el => this.inputEntry = el} is the same as this I believe. Maybe someone can correct me. The value for el must be getting passed in from somewhere, to act as the reference.

```
function (el) {
    this.inputEntry = el;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Now you can use the `useRef` hook to get some magic if you do not want to use the `useState` hook:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // @ts-ignore (us this comment if typescript raises an error)
    inputRef.current.value = "";
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputRef} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Clear input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

As I mentioned, if you are using `useState` that is the best way. I wanted to show you also this special approach.

Comment: state is definitely not the best way. It is not performing. You should only cause re-renders in forms when needed, to enable / disable buttons, show validation messages or styles.

Answer (score 2):

Also after React v 16.8+ you have an ability to use hooks

```react
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const ControlledInputs = () => {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (firstName) {
      console.log('firstName :>> ', firstName);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">Name: </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="firstName"
            name="firstName"
            value={firstName}
            onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}
          />
        <button type="submit">add person</button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: What if onChange is on <form /> tag? I don't want to add onChange on every input. How do you approach this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use useState:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const [inputTitle, setInputTitle] = useState('');
```

then add value to your input component:

```
render() {
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => setInputTitle(e.target.value)} 
value={inputTitle} />
<button onClick={handleSubmit} type="submit">Submit</button>
}
```

On your submit handler function:

```
setInputTitle('');
 document.querySelector('input').defaultValue = '';
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the defaultValue property, useRef, and onClick to achieve this.

`let ref = useRef()`

and then inside the return:

`<input type="text" defaultValue="bacon" ref={ref} onClick={() => ref.current.value = ""} />`

also if you want to use onChange for the input it wouldn't require any more configuration and you can just use it. If you want to  have a dynamic defaultValue then you absolutely can, with useState.

Answer (score 0):

On the event of onClick

```
this.state={
  title:''
}

sendthru=()=>{
  document.getElementByid('inputname').value = '';
  this.setState({
     title:''
})
}
```

```
<input type="text" id="inputname" className="form-control" ref={el => this.inputTitle = el} />   
<button className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.sendthru}>Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to reset the input in React is by implementing the **onBlur** inside the input.

onBlur={cleanSearch}

ej:

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState('')

const handleSearch = ({target}) =>{
    setSearch(target.value)
}



const cleanSearch = () =>setSearch('')


 <input
       placeholder="Search…"
       inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
       value={search}
       onChange={handleSearch}
       onBlur={cleanSearch}
   />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const handleChange = event => {
    setMessage(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setMessage('');
  };
  <input
        id="message"
        name="message"
        type="text"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={message}
      />

      <button onClick={handleClick}>Clear Field</button>
```

Answer (score -6):

The way I cleared my form input values was to add an id to my form tag.
Then when I handleSubmit I call this.clearForm()

In the clearForm function I then use document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Button from './components/Button';
import Input from './components/Input';

class App extends Component {  
  state = {
    item: "", 
    list: []
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.clearForm();
  }

handleFormSubmit = event => {
   this.clearForm()
   event.preventDefault()
   const item = this.state.item

    this.setState ({
        list: [...this.state.list, item],
            })

}

handleInputChange = event => {
  this.setState ({
    item: event.target.value 
  })
}

clearForm = () => {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset(); 
  this.setState({
    item: ""
  })
}



  render() {
    return (
      <form id="myForm">
      <Input

           name="textinfo"
           onChange={this.handleInputChange}
           value={this.state.item}
      />
      <Button
        onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}
      >  </Button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why are you not just using `ref` instead of id + document.getElementById ? I do not see this as an improvement to the accepted answer

Comment: Playing devil's advocate, the ref system was introduced three weeks after this answer, on 16.3, so maybe he didn't knew a better method. But I agree that needs to be updated.